# setting config property for hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am able to load my hazelcast.xml file when using the FileSystemXmlConfig.  However, I was only able to use that on the hazelcast server - I also need to run the hazelcast client.  However, I could not figure out how to use the FileSystemXmlConfig for instantiating ClientConfig in Hazelcast.

Another thing I am trying is to set the system properties via code (not through the launcher).  However, when I tried this, it does not appear to have picked my hazelcast.xml file since I can see that my store load were not called (they get called when I use the server setup with FileSystemXmlConfig copied below) but not when I try setting system properties (via System or via Properties).  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**Not working (System.setProperty with XML file name passed in)**

```
    Config config = new Config();
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.config", "C:/Users/userName/workspace/HazelcastTest/config/hazelcast.xml");
    HazelcastInstance hcast= Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

**Not working (System.setProperty with XML file location passed in)**

```
    Config config = new Config();
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.config", "C:/Users/userName/workspace/HazelcastTest/config/");
    HazelcastInstance hcast= Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

**Not Working (used via Properties)**

```
    Config config = new Config();
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("hazelcast.config", "C:/Users/userName/workspace/HazelcastTest/config/hazelcast.xml");
    HazelcastInstance hcast= Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

**Works with FileSystemXmlConfig**

```
Config config = new FileSystemXmlConfig("C:/Users/userName/workspace/HazelcastTest/config/hazelcast.xml");
HazelcastInstance hcast= Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the XmlClientConfigBuilder

```
ClientConfig config = new XmlClientConfigBuilder(yourfile).build();
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config)
```

Comment: For the client, why wouldn't it still pick up on the hazelcast.config system property?  The docs appear to indicate it should work for either (storage or client).